# Pass a value to a function within underscore.js delay

Tags: underscore.js

I am trying to do this, using the underscore.js library.

```
function replaceText(tab){
  removeText();
  _.delay(appendText(value), 1000)
}
```

but it doesn't work. It works with a simple setTimeout.

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
_.delay(appendText, 1000, value)
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#delay; `_.delay(function, wait, *arguments)`:

"If you pass the optional arguments, they will be forwarded on to the function when it is invoked."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few different ways.

Use partial application:

```
function replaceText(tab){
  removeText();
  _.delay(_.partial(appendText, value), 1000);
}
```

Bind the function:

```
function replaceText(tab){
  removeText();
  _.delay(appendText.bind(null, value), 1000);
}
```

Or use an anonymous function:

```
function replaceText(tab){
  removeText();
  _.delay(function(){
    appendText(value);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: All of these suggestions are overkill, underscore's `_.delay` simply takes optional arguments at the end that it passes as arguments to the function

Comment: @GeorgeJempty ahh, nice. Yup, OP should probably mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @idbehold glad I didn't offend you, you do have a good grasp of other methods from Underscore, but sometimes simplest is best ;)